# jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, jestjs, yarnpkg

We have a Node app and we are trying to migrate our test cases to Jest.In local development environment, everything is working fine.We are able to run tests.When configuring CI on Jenkins, we are getting a lot of @providesModule naming collision warnings and the build eventually fails.We are not a react or react native app.

What we suspect from our analysis is that Jest is trying to create its own dependency graph in CI rather than from yarn lock, and so having these weird provide modules collision warnings.

How can we avoid Jest in doing so.In local however it is not showing any such warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem when trying to integrate Jest testing into my CI configuration. The solution I found was to use npm install instead of yarn install. I think it may have been a problem with yarn caching.

See this thread and this answer in particular: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13364#issuecomment-312500564

## Edit

Another method I found to get around this was to remove the yarn cache before running yarn install. Here is an example GitLab CI config entry for a Heroku deployment.

```
image: node:8.11.3

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - rm -rf .yarn
    - yarn install
  script:
    - yarn test
```

Alternatively, using npm commands in place of yarn seemed to also fix the issue. In that case, you would not need to remove the yarn cache.